# Computing Difference between two count(*)

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a two queries that operate on the same table and return avg(*) results. I want to select the difference between two values but I am unable to do it. Please help.

I have tried using

```
Select t1.l1 - t2.l2
from (select avg(col) as l1 from...) as t1,
     (select avg(col) as l2 from...) as t2;
```

But it keeps on giving me error messages. Saying missing right parenthesis etc.

Comment: Include your actual query, if you have a syntax error.  At least one problem is probably the `*` in the `avg()`.  The `as` in the `from` clause is also problematic in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AVG` on specific column not `*` and there is no need for `CROSS JOIN`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91ac0/1/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE ta1(col INT);
INSERT INTO ta1 VALUES(5);
CREATE TABLE ta2(col INT);
INSERT INTO ta2 VALUES(3);

SELECT 
  (select avg(col) as l1 from ta1) - (select avg(col) as l2 from ta2) AS result
FROM  DUAL;
```

Another possibility:

**[SqlFiddleDemo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91ac0/7/0)**

```
SELECT SUM(l1) AS result
FROM(
  select avg(col) as l1 from ta1
  UNION ALL
  select - avg(col) as l1 from ta2
  ) t;
```

Comment: @muqsitnawaz Provide your query and data

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain `count()` is one of the few aggregate functions that can be used with `*` as, in that case, it just counts all the records where the actual column content doesn't matter.

For things like average, max, min and so on, they require *data* to work on, so you need to give them an actual column.

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions011.htm) for `avg` (my emphasis):

> This function takes as an argument ***any numeric datatype or any nonnumeric datatype that can be implicitly converted to a numeric datatype.*** The function returns the same datatype as the numeric datatype of the argument.

Or, in graphical form
[image]

---

On the [other hand](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm#SQLRF00624), count includes this clause:

> If you specify the asterisk (*), then this function returns all rows, including duplicates and nulls.

[image]

So you can see that using `*` in the `avg` function is not really allowed.

Comment: The problem is not really avg(*) I just wrote * to mean it could be any column. In my rather complex query, I am using an actual column.

Comment: @muqsitnawaz, that sort of detail is something you might want to specify up front next time. In fact, show your *actual* query, that will mean we don't have to attempt psychic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following in sql:

```
SELECT SUM(l1) - sum(l2) from
(
SELECT avg(fieldname) as l1 , 0 as l2
  FROM table as t1
  UNION
  select 0, avg(fieldname) as l2 from table as t2
  )as t1
```